# How to send email from contact form in R Shiny

Tags: r, curl, shiny, shiny-server, blastula

I implemented a contact form in an Shiny app and use the package 'blastula' and its function 'smtp_send' to send the message to the email address given by the sender. The code is:

```
library(shiny)
library(blastula)
library(shinyAce)

ui = fluidPage(
  fluidPage(
    wellPanel(
      textInput("from"   , "From:"   , value="...@..."),
      textInput("to"     , "To:"     , value="...@..."),
      textInput("subject", "Subject:", value="This is the subject"),

      p("Message", style="font-weight: bold;"),
      aceEditor("msg", value="This is the message"),
      br(),
      actionButton("send", "Send email!")
    )
  )   
)

server <- function(input, output)
{
  observe(
  {
    if(is.null(input$send) || input$send==0) return(NULL)

    Email = compose_email(body = input$msg, header = NULL, footer = NULL, title = NULL)
    Credentials = creds_anonymous(host = "smtp...", port = 25, use_ssl = TRUE)

    smtp_send(email = Email, to = input$to, from = input$from, subject = input$subject, credentials = Credentials)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Running this script locally and using port=25 gives error message: 'Warning: Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory: RCPT failed: 550'.

Using port=465 or port=587 gives error message: 'Warning: Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory: Timeout was reached: [smtp...:465] Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds'.

When running the script on a server using port=25 gives error message: 'Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer'.

I checked the address of the smtp server, it should be right. It is a server that does not require an account.

Does anybody have any idea why the code is not working?

Answer (score 3):

I have extracted the way how I manage email problems with my app -- gmail way works for outlook one i am not sure since i havent checked it in a while.

Replace the details with your own, gmail way is commented first.

Code bellow, and ignore the slovene in between. They are also some check when some one can send and email and if address is correct and so on...

It might help..

EDIT: Problem have to be defined and your email address should be gmail.com.

```
library(shiny)
# library (RDCOMClient)
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_241/') 
library(mailR)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyjs)

ui = fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  fluidPage(
    br(),
    fluidRow(
      column(12,align="center",
             h1(icon("envelope", lib = "font-awesome"))),
      br(),
      column(12,align="center",
             textInput("telo", "Problem statement","", width = "400px",
                       placeholder= "obvezno izpolnite!"),
             br(),
             textInput("kontakt","Your working email - necessary!","",
                       placeholder = 'ime.priimek@gmail.com'),
             helpText("Test email= Thorin@gmail.si"),
             actionButton("send", "Send",icon("fas fa-arrow-up", lib = "font-awesome")),
             br())),
    br(),
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             br()))
  )



)   


server <- function(input, output,session)
{
  disable("send")
  ###################################################################################### pošlji email, telo strani
  testek11<-function(failed = FALSE) {
    modalDialog(
      title="",
      fluidRow(column(12,align="center",
                      "SEND.")),
      br(),
      easyClose = FALSE,
      footer=fluidRow(column=12,align="center",
                      modalButton("OK",icon=icon("fas fa-check-circle"))
      )
    )
  } 

  observeEvent(input$send,{
    #showModal(testek21())
    shinyjs::disable("send")
    shinyjs::disable("nazaj2")
    shinyjs::disable("telo")
    shinyjs::disable("kontakt")


    ## gmail way
    Sys.sleep(2)

    # send.mail(from = paste(input$username,"@domain.com",sep=""),
    #           to = c("test99@gmail.com"),
    #           subject = paste("Aplikacija NNP: Problem:",input$kontakt,sep=" OD "),
    #           body =  paste(input$telo,input$username,sep=" // OD // "),
    #           smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465,
    #                       user.name = "test99@gmail.com",
    #                       passwd = "pass", ssl = TRUE),
    #           authenticate = TRUE,
    # send = TRUE)


    ## outlook way -- possibly outdated

    # OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
    # outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
    # outMail[["To"]] = "ur email adrres to where you want to send -- you can make it reactive"
    # outMail[["subject"]] = "subject"
    # outMail[["body"]] <- "body"
    # outMail$Send()
    # 
    shinyjs::enable("send")
    shinyjs::enable("nazaj2")
    shinyjs::enable("telo")
    shinyjs::enable("kontakt")
    showModal(testek11())
    updateTextInput(session,"telo",value="",placeholder = "Obvezno izpolnite!")
    updateTextInput(session,"kontakt",value="",placeholder = 'ime.priimek@gmail.si')
  })

  ##### enabling maile pa to kdaj lahko klikne send

  mailhelp <- reactiveValues(hmm=FALSE)
  mailhelp2 <- reactiveValues(hmm2=FALSE)



  observeEvent(input$telo,{
    if(input$telo != ""){
      isolate(mailhelp$hmm <- TRUE)
    }
    else{
      isolate(mailhelp$hmm <- FALSE)
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$kontakt,{
    if(grepl("@gmail.com",input$kontakt) |grepl("@GMAIL.CON",input$kontakt) ){
      isolate(mailhelp2$hmm2 <- TRUE)
    }
    else{
      isolate(mailhelp2$hmm2 <- FALSE)
    }
  })

  observe({
    if(mailhelp2$hmm2 & mailhelp$hmm){
      shinyjs::enable("send")
    }
    else{
      shinyjs::disable("send")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks! I would also be interested why using the the function from the blastula package does not work yet. The advantage of blastula is that you do not need Java.

Comment: I have no idea about blastula beacuse i have never tired it. to be fair this app is also 2 years old, and i am sure there are much better solutions now -- but hey as long as it works do not *** with it :D...